# Facing issue in understanding some concept. Gauss Divergence Theorem problem.

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Question. If $F = (x^2+y-4)i + 3xyj + (2xz+z^2)k$

Evaluate $\iint(\nabla\times F)\cdot n\ dS$

where $S$ is the surface of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$ above the xy-plane.

If we use Gauss Divergence Theorem, then $\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times F)$ will be divergence of curl of F that is $0$. So I'm unable to understand how to proceed in this question.

Kindly guide me for the same. Thank you.

Comment: Divergence theorem is not the intended solution - it would be Stokes' theorem, but you are welcome to calculate the curl in order to use divergence theorem instead.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes actually I've been working over problems in the segment of divergence theorem for now

Comment: To apply the Divergence Theorem, you need a closed surface.

Comment: It is a direct application of Stokes' theorem but if this is a problem in the segment of divergence theorem, please first close the surface with a disk at $z = 0$. Now apply divergence theorem. The net flux is zero but it includes the disk at $z = 0$ and so find flux through the disk at $z = 0$ and subtract from the total flux (which is zero). To find flux through the disk, first find the curl of the vector field. Let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you @MathLover I understand the concept now and also the solution